# Would a question about a specific application for macOS be acceptable?

Tags: support, questions

Would a question about where to find an Esperanto dictionary for the Dictionary application used on the macOS be acceptable, or is it stretching the limit a little too much?

Answer (score 3):

I think that would be quite on-topic and really useful. That's the kind of questions SO was created for originally: things that are hard to find otherwise but have a clear answer.